# Getting my own IP address by connect()ing using UDP socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, udp

I've heard that I can get my own IP address(not 127.0.0.1), by creating a `UDP socket` and connecting() to a valid destination IP address like Google.

However, I could not find any reference or example for this.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

---

```
char* get_my_ip() {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr; // client address
    socklen_t addrlen;
    char remoteIP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char *ip_addr;
    ip_addr = malloc(sizeof(char) * INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    int rv;

    struct addrinfo hints, *ai, *p;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo("8.8.8.8", "http", &hints, &ai)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        exit(1);
    }
    // loop through all the results and make a socket
    for(p = ai; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
            p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("UDP: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("UDP: connect");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "UDP: failed to bind socket\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr, &addrlen);

    // deal with both IPv4 and IPv6:
    if (remoteaddr.ss_family == AF_INET) {
        struct sockaddr_in *s = (struct sockaddr_in *)&remoteaddr;
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, remoteIP, addrlen);
    }
    else { // AF_INET6
        struct sockaddr_in6 *s = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&remoteaddr;
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &s->sin6_addr, remoteIP, addrlen);
    }
    printf("IP_ADDRESS:%s", remoteIP);

    freeaddrinfo(ai); // all done with this structure
    close(sockfd);

    strcpy(ip_addr, remoteIP);
    return ip_addr;
}
```

Comment: If you get -1 from a system call you must call perror() *immediately,* not after calling another system call, such as close() in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `connect()` and then `getsockname()` on your socket. It will return the IP address the socket is now bound to, which has been chosen by the IP routing tables as the best route to the target address.

However that is not necessarily the IP address you are looking for, unless you only have one external IP address.

If you're talking about your *public* IP address on the other side of a modem or router, this technique has no applicability at all.

Comment: I have written a function `get_my_ip()`, and appended the function code to the end of the question. Although it worked when I had the same code inside `main()`, as I put the code to a separate function and called `get_my_ip` inside main, it prints some weird characters(�&^�T) for my IP. Do you know what is missing from my program? Thank you.